# Django emailmultialternatives include round bracket in from email

Tags: python, django, django-email

I'm trying to send email in django using EmailMultiAlternatives. Here is my code:

```
email_msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,text_content,"Abc (ABC) <abc@abc.com>",['abc@abc.com'])
email_msg.send()
```

the email is sent out fine but the contents inside the bracket in my from email were missing. So when I received the email, from email is like this "`Abc <abc@abc.com>`" instead of "`Abc (ABC) <abc@abc.com>`". 
If I try to escape using backslash like `"Abc \(ABC\) <abc@abc.com>"`, it's working in Gmail but not in outlook.